# autocomplete.js not working in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, typeahead.js

I am a big noob at javascript, so maybe the solution is very very simple.

I have a form with an autocomplete field done via twitter's typeahead.js .

The typeahead for field place_name loads both a prefetch and a remote resource of cities and associated IDs.

e.g. typing "piac" it calls up

```
[ {"id" : "22351", "value": "Piacenza, Emilia-Romagna, IT"} ...... ]
```

on Chrome, it properly populates the place_name field and sets an hidden field place_id with the ID value.
So, when user types "piac", then types arrow-down to select Piacenza, then the typeahead field loses focus, both place_name and place_id fields are correctly set and properly passed to the page recipient of the form.

On IE10 compatibility mode , true IE10, as well a  IE9-8-7 , I am unable to make the typeahead function work. I type piac, piace ... any string, the typeahead functionality is not triggered.

The page skeleton comes from initializr.com, so it is html5 boilerplate + bootstrap without bootstrap's own typeahead.

These are the relevant code snippets:

HTML in page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=http://sandbox/public/css/bootstrap.min.css>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=http://sandbox/public/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=http://sandbox/public/css/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=http://sandbox/public/css/main.css>
    <script src=http://sandbox/public/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js         </script>
</head>
... (page)
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src=http://sandbox/public/js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js><\/script>')</script>
    <script src=http://sandbox/public/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js></script>
    <script src=http://sandbox/public/js/typeahead.min.js></script>
    <script src=http://sandbox/public/js/hogan.min.js></script>
    <script src=http://sandbox/public/js/main.js></script>
```

form fields html:

```
<label for="place_name" class="input-block-level muted">Where do you live?</label>        
<input placeholder="Type the first letters (e.g. bat for Batman, TR)" class="input-block-level" id="place_name" autocomplete="off" name="place_name" type="text">
<input id="place_id" name="place_id" type="hidden">
```

contained in main.js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#place_name').typeahead({                              
    name: 'place_name',
    prefetch: '/public/json/pplca12.json',
    remote: 'http://sandbox/public/jsonplaces/%QUERY'  ,                                           
    limit: 10                                      
  });
  $('#place_name').on("typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted", function(e,datum) { 
    document.getElementById('place_id').value = datum.id;
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong or overlooking? I was unable to see any error at all through IE's dev tools.

Many thanks

Comment: Slaks, I am usingIE10, but as said above, tried also (through its dev tools) to emulate 7, 8, 9. None worked.

Comment: Sorry; I missed that line.